# 2 Find Conditions with one variable

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, pagination

Right now I have only one condition in my Projects.paginate
Code is below

```
   def list
        @projects = Project.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100, :order => (sort_column + ' ' + arrow), :conditions => ["description LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])
```

I want to put another condition here but its is proving to be difficult. I'v tried

```
   @projects = Project.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100, :order => (sort_column + ' ' + arrow), :conditions => ["description OR name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])
```

but im getting a bind error from the SQL controller. Any ideas? I cant use the = sign either.

Comment: I don't really know about Rails, but `SELECT ... WHERE description OR name LIKE '%foo%'` is not really valid SQL, or at least it wouldn't do what you think it does. It needs to be `WHERE description LIKE '%foo%' OR name LIKE '%foo%'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two bind variables in your conditions array:

```
qt = "%#{query}%"
@projects = Project.paginate(:conditions => 
              ["description LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", qt, qt], ..)
```

Comment: Ah. Quite strange considering both qt and qt have the same value. You'd think SQL would be able to understand with just one variable. Anyway thank you! this did solve my problem